# SVG inlined in html not displayed correctly (by chrome)

Tags: html, svg

I have a svg which I create in python using [etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Here is the resulting [pure svg](https://gist.github.com/RudolfVonKrugstein/28e82949de9c86ff75c68cd7aebd9a15), which is displayed correctly by the browser.

Now I embed this svg in a n html like this: [html with svg](https://gist.github.com/RudolfVonKrugstein/d972bbbc2f71a76578fb8c2d5a7beeab)

Unfortanly my browser (chrome) does not display it correctly anymore, it only shows the textfield.

is there Something wrong with my svg? Are there limitations to in-html rendering, which I am breaking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** The corrected working code is at the bottom of the post.

There are four basic rules to follow in order to achieve at least a decent amount of cross-browser compatibility when it comes to displaying SVGs.

**1. Embedding vs external loading**

If there is no requirement to manipulate the SVG content, like changing shapes or fills through CSS and/or JavaScript, loading it externally is the preferred way.

That means using this

```
<body>
    <!-- content -->
        <img src="external.svg"/>
    <!-- content -->
</body>
```

instead of this

```
<body>
    <!-- content -->
    <svg>
        <!-- SVG content -->
    </svg>
    <!-- content -->
</body>
```

Embedding SVG code has some advantages of course but it also comes with issues caused by vendor specific browser implementations and missing functionality (non-existent support for SVG gradients etc.)

**2. Use the viewBox attribute**

When embedding SVG content into HTML pages browsers need to know how the SVG content relates to space reserved for displaying them (also known as the viewport). By defining the `viewBox` attribute browsers can translate all the coordinates from "within" the SVG into a relative coordinate system which ensures proper display in all browsers simply because there is no guessing involved on the browser part.

If `viewBox` is not defined some browsers like IE will either mess up proportions or sometimes even fail to display the SVG entirely.

**3. Don't use exotic XML namespaces**

SVGs require only one declared namespace to become fully usable with browsers.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg>
```

Adding any additional namespace greatly increases the risk of SVG not displaying at all. The only exception is `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` which is used for loading external SVG storages, a form of SVG sprites which is great for combining multiple SVGs into one file.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">...</svg>
```

**4. Don't use namespace prefixes**

Unlike XHTML in HTML5 namespaces are implicitly defined which means code like this

```
<svg>
    <!-- SVG content -->        
    <ns0:path d="..." />
    <!-- SVG content -->
</svg>
```

will simply not work as expected and is often simply ignored. The proper way to define SVG content within HTML5 is to just not use namespace prefixes.

```
<svg>
    <!-- SVG content -->        
    <path d="..." />
    <!-- SVG content -->
</svg>
```

If the above rules are applied to the original code it should work in all browsers.

It is also worth noting that there are a lot of tools out there which can be very helpful in preparing SVG resources for browser use. One of the best is probably [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) which can also be used to automate building and deploying SVGs in projects.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is the funky namespacing in that file.  The SVG elements are not being parsed as SVG elements, they are being parsed as type `HTMLUnknownElement`. Basically the browser doesn't recognise them.

Load your SVG into Inkscape and save it out as "Plain SVG", or even better as "Optimized SVG".  Then use that file in your HTML instead.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to link to your svg instead of including it in the body like that:

```
<img src="svg.svg">
```